# How can I use xindy on a system with libncurses.so.6?

Tags: errors, texlive, installing, linux, xindy

My GNU/Linux system (Arch) now has `libncurses.so.6` rather than `libncurses.so.5`. But I have upstream's vanilla TeX Live (fully updated) and `xindy` wants `libncurses.so.5`:

```
xindy --version
```

produces the following error

```
xindy release: 2.5.1
xindy script version: 1.18
/usr/local/texlive/bin/xindy.run: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And `ldd` can confirm the problem:

```
ldd /usr/local/texlive/bin/xindy.run
```

gives

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc07997000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fab4d1b1000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fab4cf79000)
    libncurses.so.5 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fab4cd75000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fab4c9d1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fab4d4af000)
```

How can I use `xindy` without changing my operating system, while using vanilla TeX Live?

2 strategies have occurred to me:

1. compile `xindy` from sources against `libncurses.so.6`;
2. compile and install `libncurses.so.5` alongside `libncurses.so.6`.

Option (2) can be dodgy or can be fine, depending on the details. My suspicion is it may be dodgy for this library, simply because no packages are available for the old version of the library, which might mean there are problems having both installed. Moreover, since everything else is compiled against the new version, I'm not sure whether this would be enough for `xindy` anyway.

Option (1) I have no idea about. I don't know if this is even vaguely doable or, in fact, where the sources are or what might be required to compile them. (I don't suppose there's any chance a pre-compiled binary is available somewhere? But that is probably hoping for too much ;).)

What is the most practicable approach?

Comment: I have absolutly no idea what libncurses.so.5 is, but it sounds as a question that should go to the texlive list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I believe that it emulates the kind of semi-graphical interface which can be used at the command line a looks like ASCII art. (Don't know if you've ever used programmes which use this kind of interface or not.)

Comment: It's a library for terminal user interfaces

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is an answer. It is, at least, a workaround.

***This is specific to Arch Linux.*** It may be that it can be modified for other systems, should the need arise, but that is not something I have any knowledge of at this time. (My other system runs Fedora where there's no issue at the moment.)

---

On Arch Linux, you can install the AUR package `ncurses5-compat-libs`. As I understand it, this is using source with the same major version as the main repo's `ncurses` package:

`ncurses5-compat-libs`:

```
Repository     : aur
Name           : ncurses5-compat-libs
Version        : 6.0-2
URL            : http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html
AUR Page       : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs
Depends On     : glibc  gcc-libs  sh
License        : MIT
Votes          : 82
Popularity     : 35.48
Out of Date    : No
Maintainer     : Barthalion
Submitted      : Dydd Gwener 18 mis Medi 2015 22:03:12 BST
Last Modified  : Dydd Gwener 18 mis Medi 2015 22:03:12 BST
Description    : System V Release 4.0 curses emulation library, ABI 5
```

`ncurses`:

```
Repository     : core
Name           : ncurses
Version        : 6.0-3
Description    : System V Release 4.0 curses emulation library
Architecture   : x86_64
URL            : http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html
Licences       : MIT
Groups         : None
Provides       : libncurses++w.so=6-64  libformw.so=6-64  libmenuw.so=6-64  libpanelw.so=6-64  libncursesw.so=6-64
Depends On     : glibc  gcc-libs
Optional Deps  : None
Conflicts With : None
Replaces       : None
Download Size  : 1007.14 KiB
Installed Size : 3407.00 KiB
Packager       : Evangelos Foutras <evangelos@foutrelis.com>
Build Date     : Dydd Mawrth 15 mis Medi 2015 04:47:59 BST
Validated By   : MD5 Sum  SHA256 Sum  Signature
```

The difference, I think, is in the way the packages are built:

`ncurses5-compat-libs`'s `PKGBUILD` includes this code:

```
build() {
  cd $_pkgname-${pkgver/_/-}

  ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man \
     --with-shared --with-normal --without-debug --without-ada \
     --enable-widec --enable-pc-files --with-cxx-binding --with-cxx-shared \
     --with-abi-version=5
  make
}
```

whereas `ncurse`'s `PKGBUILD` uses this code:

```
build() {
  cd $pkgname-${pkgver/_/-}

  ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man \
     --with-shared --with-normal --without-debug --without-ada \
     --enable-widec --enable-pc-files --with-cxx-binding --with-cxx-shared \
     --enable-ext-colors --enable-ext-mouse
  make
}
```

So I'm assuming that the `--with-abi-version=5` is the key here, and that this option is what ensures that `libncursesw.so.5` is built rather than `libncursesw.so.6`. (`libncurses.so.5` and `libncurses.so.6` are just symbolic links to `libncursesw.so.5` and `libncursesw.so.6` respectively, which support 'wide' characters on terminals for better international support, I think).

There is also an AUR package providing the 32-bit versions of the libraries provided by `libncurses5-compat-libs` (i.e. the `5` versions of the libraries provided by the main repo's `lib32-ncurses`).

Comment: Just a quick note: On a current Arch Linux system (x64) this does not work. Even ignoring the failing PGP checks of the AUR packages `xindy` cannot find the `.so.5` files (although `which` shows the correct location).

Comment: @TeXnician Have you tried `ldconfig`? If `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libncurses.so.5` does not show results, try `sudo ldconfig` to update the cache.

Comment: @Schweinebacke No results. Even after updating the cache. And for libncurses only the following `libncursesw.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6
 libncursesw.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.6
 libncursesw.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.5
 libncursesw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so
 libncursesw.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so
 libncurses++w.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.6
 libncurses++w.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so`

Comment: @TeXnician What's the location of `libncurses.so.5` and `libncurses.so.5.9`? Is the location searched by `ldconfig`? If not, add the path or make a symlink into `/usr/lib/`. BTW: Here (SuSE Leap or SuSE Tumbleweed) `libncursesw.so.5.9` and `libncurses.so.5.9` are different binaries.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Done, new error: `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy.run: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`. I do not seem to get a 64-bit compatibility version of libncurses5, but the xindy binary is 64-bit.

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, you need the 64bit library.

Comment: @TeXnician This setup still works for me on an x64 Arch Linux system (with updated packages, of course). Moreover, I don't have to ignore any PGP failures in order to build or install. If you do, there's something wrong with your configuration. Results of `ldconfig -p | grep libncurses`:  ...

Comment: `libncursesw.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6
        libncursesw.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.6
        libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5
        libncursesw.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so
        libncursesw.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so
        libncurses++w.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.6
        libncurses++w.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so.5
        libncurses++w.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncurses++w.so`

Comment: @TeXnician You seem to have installed the 32bit compatibility library rather than the 64bit compatibility library. You should have `libncursesw.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5` whereas you actually have `libncursesw.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libncursesw.so.5` which won't work.

Comment: @cfr Well, I had both installed, but it had not recognized the 64-bit-library. To install it I needed for a Manjaro setup and a Arch setup to ignore the PGP keys. After all, doing the refresh as Schweinebacke suggested, helped. The other option was to compile xindy from source and that works too. I'll probably close my question as duplicate now.

Comment: @TeXnician Manjaro isn't Arch. But note that ignoring failures for PGP keys is wrong i.e. insecure. But Manjaro does some decidedly dodgy stuff itself anyway.

Comment: @cfr I have it tried on Manjaro *and* Arch (two different machines), but it failed to verify on both. But after all it works.

Comment: @TeXnician I can only reiterate that you have something wrong with your configuration. By default, for local packages, `pacman` only checks PGP keys if a signature is provided. That is, it does not fail if the package is unsigned, but only if there is a non-matching signature. If you are signing the packages you build, you would need to add the key to those `pacman` trusts. Otherwise, if you build without signing, `pacman` will not complain with the default settings.

Comment: @cfr Well, the [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=ncurses5-compat-libs) contains a signature, which is obviously not in the trusted cache. But however, the key is that it works after all.

Comment: @TeXnician But that's not being used to sign the package. It is a signature for the source.

Comment: Just for the record, as it can be a problem under Gentoo, too: Install `ncurses:5` parallel to `ncurses:6`; it does not make any problems, since the versions are in different slots and `portage` keeps everything together. Afterwards, `xindy` works again.