# Running xindy on up-to-date OS

Tags: errors, texlive, linux, xindy

cfr once asked and answered the following question: [How can I use xindy on a system with libncurses.so.6?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281296/124577)

In short: every run of xindy/texindy on an actual file (not the help menu) does end with something like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy.run: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that the given solution does not work anymore nowadays. Running an up-to-date TeX Live 2017 (vanilla) and Arch Linux x64 with access to AUR I tried to use the packages given in the answer. Unfortunately both cannot be validated and even skipping the signature check does not help.

Probably it could work compiling xindy manually against another library, but where are the official sources with version 2.5.1 (or newer)?

Or is there maybe another way of getting xindy to work on a "modern" OS?

*Update:* I've tried to compile the ancient sources from 2010 from [here](http://xindy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xindy/) (CVS) where any essential binaries and code files are from 1996 (no luck). And the xindy home page talks about xindy 2.2 being a release candidate, although TeX Live 2017 ships with xindy 2.5.1.

*Update 2:* As @DavidCarlisle showed in the chat the usual behavior would be

```
$ xindy --version
xindy release: 2.5.1
xindy script version: 1.18
xindy kernel version: 3.0
CLISP version 2.49.50 (2017-03-19) (built on desktop-new [192.168.1.4])
    architecture: X86_64
```

Because of the missing library the kernel version and the clisp version do not even show up.

Comment: This was reported to TL list in march http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-March/039806.html

Comment: Is it actually looking for a specific version of a lib? Like `.so.6` and you have `.so.7` Then perhaps just a soft link will help.

Comment: "up-to-date OS" does not mean that it does not provide `libncurses.so.5`. I'm using an up-to-date OS, that provides both `libncurses.so.5` and `libncurses.so.6`. It's a political decision of the distributor not to provide older libs or even remove them on updates.

Comment: @daleif I tried softlinking, but it does not help when running xindy. Actually it gave me a file too short error. But I could not even link it to a `libncurses.so.6`, because Arch has only `libncurses.so         libncursesw.so        libncurses++w.so.6.0
libncurses++.so       libncurses++w.so.6    libncursesw.so.6.0
libncurses++w.so      libncursesw.so.6`.

Comment: if xindy is looking for `libncurses.so.6` then try and soft link it to `libncurses.so`

Comment: As far as I can see it is linked against `libncurses.so.5` so try softlinking that to `libncurses.so` to see if that is enough

Comment: @daleif That's what I've tried and got the error with "File too short".

Comment: Short status report: Compiling manually from TeX Live binaries completes, but the installation is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after fiddling around a lot, here are two working solutions:

1. *Do as cfr suggested*

   1. Install compatibility packages, on Arch this is `ncurses5-compat-libs` or `lib32-ncurses5-compat-libs` (as your architecture of TL needs it). Currently the package `ncurses5-compat-libs` is marked out-of-date, but it still works. And you need to skip integrity check on those packages (currently) using something like

      ```
       yaourt --m-arg --skipchecksums --m-arg --skippgpcheck -Sb ncurses5-compat-libs
      ```
   2. Run `sudo ldconfig` to rebuild the library cache.
   3. `xindy` should run.
2. *Compile from scratch* (should work for all distributions)

   1. Download TeX Live from its source repos (see instructions [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/build.html))
   2. Change to the xindy directory (`utils/xindy`)
   3. Do `./configure`. If it requires you compile the needed TeX Live basics first.
   4. Do `make`. You will encounter an error `Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex`. Open the perl file in the `xindy-src/modules/inputenc` directory and escape the opening `{` in l. 11 (like `if (/\\indexentry\{(.+)--([8-9a-f][0-9a-f])\}\{1\}/) {`). Run `make` again.
   5. Have fun with the installation. A good try is to backup TLs origin xindy and to replace it. If it doesn't work look for one of the guides.